# Trouble rewriting expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have trouble rewriting an algebraic expression again. I have to go from:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}*(1+x)^2}$$

to

$$\frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

I'm not seeing it, what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the $*$ a multiplication?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $2$ in the last expression

Comment: @NazimJ Yes the * is a multiplication.

Comment: @Andrei Sorry, you're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}(1+x)^2}
&= \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\frac{{1-x}}{{1+x}}(1+x)^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}(1-x)(1+x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1-x}(1+x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, similar approach to the one used above by Andrei. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first step you are looking for is this one

$\frac{1}{2\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}*(1+x)^2} = \frac{1}{2\frac{\sqrt{1-x}*\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{1+x}*\sqrt{1+x}}*(1+x)^2}$

Comment: Alternative way of solving it compared to the other two answers. It's clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}(1+x)^2}&=\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}(1+x)(1+x)}\\&=\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}}\sqrt{1+x}\sqrt{1+x}(1+x)}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x}(1+x)}\\&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+x)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah I get it now, expanding the (1+x)^2 into factors (one containing two roots) did the trick. Not a trick I'm used to using, but will keep it in the back of my mind. Thanks a bunch!